# .htaccess Rewrite Rule Problems

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

can anyone help me with htaccess rewrite?
I have now links like:

`http://site.com/all_users.php?uid=cv19143939y`

but i want something like this

`http://site.com/profile/cv19143939y`

Im try with this

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+) all_users.php?uid=$1 [L]`

and this

`RewriteRule ^profile/$1 all_users.php?uid=$1 [L]`

but simple dont work..

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression doesn't accept a-z

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9a-z]+) all_users.php?uid=$1 [L]
```