# Need help .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need help to rewrite URL with htaccess, now my url is

http://site.com/index.php?user=ln12666279n

i want make it like

http://site.com/user/ln12666279n

any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess Rewrite Rule Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870792/htaccess-rewrite-rule-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(user)/([\w\d]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?%1=%2
```